# Get Query Params in express node js

Tags: node.js, express

The url contains all the query strings after the # key 
http://localhost:3002/callback#access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer

how do we access the params after #

Comment: The correct way of sending parameters via query string is using `?` instead of `#`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var url = 'http://localhost:3002/callback#access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer';

 function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\#&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, '    '));
};

 console.log(getUrlParameter('access_token'));
 console.log(getUrlParameter('expires_in'));
 console.log(getUrlParameter('token_type'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use `?` instead of `#`

So your url should be

> http://localhost:3002/callback?access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer
>
> Now you can get the query params with below method

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/callback', function(req, res){
  console.log('access_token: ' + req.query.access_token);
  console.log('expires_in: ' + req.query.expires_in);
  console.log('token_type: ' + req.query. token_type);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the `#` isn't sent to the server by the browser.. you can
 only parse it if the url is generated or obtained from the server. Then you can use nodes in-built `url` module to parse symbols in the url

Comment: is there any other way to access those query string ?

Comment: yes..don't send the token using the hash `#` use query params symbol `?` just as  @iagowp mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring() method:
**EDIT:**  the string you can get from response.body. You have to use body-parser or express.json

```
let str = "http://localhost:3002/callback#access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer";
    let index=str.indexOf("#");
    let res = str.substring(index+1);
```

Output:
`$ node server.js
access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer`